# Rebalance issue with spring kafka max.poll.interval.ms, max.poll.records and idleTimeBetweenPolls

Tags: spring-kafka

I am seeing the continuous rebalancing on my application. My application is developed in batch mode and here are configuration properties which have been added.

```
myapp.consumer.group.id= cg-id-local
myapp.changefeed.topic= test_topic
myapp.auto.offset.reset=latest
myapp.enable.auto.commit=false
myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=300000
myapp.max.poll.records= 20000
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=240000
myapp.concurrency = 10
```

**container factory:**

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(poSummaryCGID));
        factory.setConcurrency(poSummNoOfConsumers);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(idleTimeBetweenPolls);
```

I have few Questions here:

1. I have setup the maximum record count per poll(4 min) is 20000 and we have 10 partitions in a TOPIC. Since i setup the concurrency as 10, so 10 consumers will up and running and each will listen to 1 partition. My question here is, does the record count will be split across all the consumers like each consumer can handle 2000 records ?
2. The max.poll.interval.ms has been setup with 5 min. I am sure that the consumer will process 2000(if my above understanding is correct) records in a given poll interval(4 min) which is less than  max.poll.interval.ms which has upper bound limit. But not sure why rebalancing is happening? are there any other configuration properties i need to setup ?

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Tried with these configurations: 

myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=600000 
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000 
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=360000 

myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=300000 
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000 
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=300000 

myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=300000 
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000 
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=180000
```

EDIT FIX :
We should always
myapp.max.poll.interval.ms >
(myapp.idle.time.between.polls + myapp.max.poll.records processing time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `max.poll.records` is per consumer, not per topic or container.

If you have concurrency=10 and 10 partitions you should reduce `max.poll.records` to 2000 so that each consumer gets a max of 2000 per poll.

The container will automatically reduce the idle between polls so that the `max.poll.interval.ms` won't be exceeded, but you should be conservative with these properties (`max.poll.records` and `max.poll.interval.ms`) such that it will never be possible to exceed the interval.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your ontime support!!.  I am confused on the second answer. I am explicitly setting the idle time between polls as 4 mins so that each batch of events will be processed within max.poll.interval (5min).  Can i increase this max.poll.interval to 10 min, so that my app will process more events like 10000 records/consumer with ideal poll interval of 6 min ?

Comment: All I mean is that, say your consumer takes exactly 2 minutes to process its records. If we slept for the configured 4 minutes, we would exceed the 5 minutes and cause a rebalance; the container will reduce its sleep time to 3 minutes (- 5 seconds to avoid a race). You only need to set `idleBetweenPolls` if you want to slow your consumers down. It's quite unusual, most people want to process things as fast as possible. One reason to use it is if you have rate limits on some service that you call, which means you have to slow the consumers down.

Comment: Thanks @Gary.  The reason behind setting idealtime and making the consumer slow down is, the source events are almost duplicate events in 8 to 10 min of interval time. So i  want to poll  at start of this duration, so that my consumer will eliminate all most all duplicates and process the events within idle time limit. So i would like to request you that what is your suggestion in this scenario?

Comment: So this is the reason ,  i would  like to increase this max.poll.interval to 10 min, so that my app will process more events like 10000 records/consumer with ideal poll interval of 6 min, so that always poll interval lying in less than 10 min of max.poll.interval to avoid the rebalance.  would this be a valid configuration to set?

Comment: You can do whatever you want within the parameters I described to avoid a rebalance. It is still not clear why you have set idleBetweenPolls.

Comment: Still unable to resolve the rebalance issue. Tweaked these configurations
myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=600000
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=360000
and 
myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=300000
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=300000
and 
myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=300000
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=180000

Comment: It is too hard to read that. Better to edit the question and comment that you have done so. The logs should help you figure out why you are getting a rebalance. It will not happen if you process in time. One more time, why do you need idle between polls?

Comment: Let me explain how our source system works.  The messages will be keep on piling up in the topic every 5 to 15 min. Among these messages all most all are duplicate. So we would like to eliminate these duplicate in one poll and make the consumer wait 5 min. So when we poll next time after 5 min, there are lot of messages piled up into the kafka, and our consumer can easily remove duplicates among those consume records

Comment: Seems an odd architecture, but If you are tossing out all these dups, it is not clear why you cannot process the remaining within the max poll interval.

Comment: is my below understanding correct ?
max.poll.interval > idleTimeBetweenPolls+ processing time of batch ?

Comment: Yes but, as I said, the container will adjust down the `idleBetweenPolls` if necessary, when the record processing is complete, to avoid a rebalance. So, a rebalance should only occur if the processing time exceeds the max poll interval.

Comment: I just verified it works as expected `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=30000` and
`spring.kafka.listener.idle-between-polls=60s`, with no records to process, it polls every 25 seconds (`max.poll.interval.ms - 5000`) as I described back in the second comment.

Comment: Thanks @Gary!!! thank you so much for your help!! Now i am not seeing any rebalaning issues.!! Here is what i did.
I set these values -  
myapp.max.poll.interval.ms=600000 
myapp.max.poll.records= 2000 
myapp.idle.time.between.polls=60000
max poll inteval (600000 )> idletime(60000) + 2000 records processing time(400000)

Comment: got another question - is there a restriction on max.poll.interval.ms ? what i mean is max.poll.interval.ms value can be set any time limit as long as it is greater than idlePollTime+ processing time?   I am trying to set  max.poll.interval.ms to 15 mins But still some time i am seeing rebalance issue.

Comment: Not that I am aware of; logs (client and server) should help understand what's causing the rebalance.